# How to retrieve a value from mongoDB, by its key name?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB. I am using java and mongoDB. I have a json like,

```
[{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "AA" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "AA" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "BB" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]

    [{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"} , "HomeTown" : "BB" , 
"PhoneNumber" : { "CustName" : "xxx" , "Number" : "3403290"},
"MobileNumber" : { "CustName" : "yyy" , "Number" : "9323304302"}}]
```

In a collection all doc's have different `HomeTown`, i just know the key name `HomeTown`, how can i get the `HomeTown` values?

In mongo site, i just can find `find()` and `findOne()`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`find()` is enough.

```
db.CollectionName.find({},{HomeTown:1})
```

in java, it would be:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject field = new BasicDBObject();
field.put("HomeTown", 1);
DBCursor cursor = db.getCollection(collectionName).find(query,field);
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
    result.add(obj.getString("HomeTown"));
}
```

Comment: @Ron: Thanks for your support. I have a question, What is the meaning of `1` in field.put("HomeTown", 1);

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: What is the meaning of 1 in field.put("HomeTown", 1);

Comment: @CS 1.6, It means that Mongo will find a field `HomeTown` with **value** is `1`. I may be wrong but I've not dealt with Mongo. The `1` could also mean, limit (as in SQL).

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: It returns perfectly what i needed! Since i am a newbie, I just wanted to know what it means.

Comment: field.put("HomeTown", 1); means only return  HomeTown (and _id) ,  field.put("HomeTown", 0);  means return all fields but not HomeTown. so it means you can not both have 0 and 1 in field. db.CollectionName.find({},{HomeTown:1,PhoneNumber:0}) would be wrong.

Comment: Download mongvue: http://blog.mongovue.com/downloads/  to test it (need .NET Framework)

Comment: @Ron : I am in need of getting inner object. I post it as a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263730/how-to-get-values-of-inner-document-attribute-in-mongodb . and i also want to know where i can learn this stuffs. I am looking for a material to learn this on my own. But i couldn't able to find one, that fits for java!

Comment: @Ron This now on MongoDB 3 give "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bson.Document cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject"

Comment: BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();  line throws ---- Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException] with root cause java.util.NoSuchElementException --- error. what's the solution  @Ron

Answer (score 13):

```
 db.CollectionName.find({},{HomeTown:1,PhoneNumber:0})
```

Would be wrong, but

```
 db.CollectionName.find({},{HomeTown:1, _id:0})
```

would be right, because you need to suppress `_id` explicitly. Just FYI.

Answer (score 3):

```
Mongo m = new Mongo('localhost',27017);
DB db = m.getDB("yourDBName");
Collection coll = db.getCollection("yourCollectionName")
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("HomeTown", 1);
DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query);
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
String str;
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    str=cursor.curr().get("HomeTown").toString();
    arr.add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int value=0;value<=10;value++)
{
 DBCollection tableDetails = db.getCollection("Collection Name");
 BasicDBObject queryDetails = new BasicDBObject();
 queryDetails.put("_id", value);
 DBCursor cursorDetails =tableDetails.find(queryDetails);
 DBObject oneDetails;
 boolean Name=cursorDetails.hasNext();
 while(Name)
  { 
    oneDetails=cursorDetails.next();        
    String data=oneDetails.get("HomeTown").toString();
    System.out.println(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you meant `boolean Name=cursorDetails.hasNext();
 while(Name)` as  `while(cursorDetails.hasNext())`?!