# How to get values of inner document attribute in mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

i am new to mongoDB. I am using mongoDB in web app.

I want to know how to get the value of inner document attribute of a document.

Lets say my JSON is like,

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "4ceb753a70fdf877ef5113ca"}, "Attrr1" : "value1", "Attr2": {"innerAttr1":"innerValue1", "innerAttr2":"innerValue2"}, "Attr3" : { "innerAttr3" : "innerValue3", "innerAttr4" : "innerValue4"} }
```

For the above json, how can i get `innerValue1` and both `innerValue1` & `innerValue2`.

I tried this, but its not working for me!!!

```
BasicDBObject innerQuery = new BasicDBObject();
field.put("Attr2.innerAttr1", 1);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciative!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not get you. You need get value or set or add into collection inside of some document?

As i understand you using some driver for mongo db in java. I am not experienced in mongo driver for java. But i know ho to do this in driver or c#:

in c# mongo driver for update inner property in collection you need do following:

```
var query = Query.Eq("_id", documentId);
var update = Update.Set("Attr2.innerAttr1",1);

MongoDb.Database.GetCollection("collectionName").Update(query, update);
```

if query from above code retun one document - innerAttr1 property from Attr2 collection will be update. If i know that query return more than one document and i need update more tha one document i use such code:

```
MongoDb.Database.GetCollection("collectionName").Update(query, update, UpdateFlag.Multi);
```

I belive that the same logic in mongo driver for java.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Java driver doesn't support dot notation. That is the problem for me. But i found another way to do it. But i appreciate your effort for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer was not posted and I just found the answer, here it is

```
(BasicDBObject)(query.get("Attr2")).getString("InnerAttr1") 
where query = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next()
```

Credit goes to another post on stackoverflow.

Comment: If have the link to the other post on SO you should probably include it in your answer.

Comment: I was trying to find it but couldnt. When I do, I will include it.