# Convert dbcursor object into json

Tags: java, json, mongodb, gson

I have a java application where I want to send json data fro servlet to a jsp. I am using mongodb as a database and Gson library for Json.

I am new to Java & Mongo.

Here is the code for querying the database:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
DB database = mongoClient.getDB("MyTestDatabase");
coll = database.getCollection("players");

BasicDBObject fields = new BasicDBObject();

    fields.put("_id", 0);
    fields.put("Incident Date", 1);
    fields.put("Longitude", 1);
    fields.put("Latitude", 1);
    fields.put("Address", 1);
    fields.put("Status", 1);
    fields.put("Name", 1);

    doc.put("Address", "Mumbai");

    cursor = coll.find(doc,fields);
```

And this is the result after querying the database

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5540cae37a104f6bbfe7c9f5"} , "Incident Date" : "30/4/2015" , "Longitude" : "77.61528809" , "Latitude" : "12.9245331" , "Address" : "Mumbai" , "Status" : "Ok" , "Name" : [ "1.ABC" , "2.XYZ" , "3.PQR"]}
```

What I want to achieve is to convert the above result into a JSON and access the JSON using fields such as 'Incident Date', 'Status' by parsing the result as json. I tried to parse the original result as json but I think it doesn't work like that

Here is what I have tried.
1. Converted the 'cursor' to ArrayList

```
    List<DBObject> myList = new ArrayList<DBObject>();
    myList = cursor.toArray();
```

2. Tried to convert the ArrayList into the JSON

   ```
   JSON json =new JSON();
   String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);
   ```

I tried the following code, but I am getting this error

```
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(serialize);
    System.out.println(jelement);
    JsonObject  jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();//error at this line
    System.out.println(jobject);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"_id":{"$oid":"5540cae37a104f6bbfe7c9f5"},"Incident Date":"30/4/2015","Longitude":"77.61528809","Latitude":"12.9245331","Address":"Mumbai","Status":"Ok","Culprits Name":["1.ABC","2.XYZ","3.PQR"]}]
at com.google.gson.JsonElement.getAsJsonObject(JsonElement.java:90)
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over `cursor` and push data into `JSONObject` and then put `jsonObject` into `jsonarray` like this :

```
public JSONArray getJsonData() throws JSONException {
  JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
  BasicDBObject criteria = new BasicDBObject();
  BasicDBObject projections = new BasicDBObject();
  criteria.put("Address", "Mumbai");
  projections.put("_id", 0);
  projections.put("Incident Date", 1);
  projections.put("Longitude", 1);
  projections.put("Latitude", 1);
  projections.put("Address", 1);
  projections.put("Status", 1);
  projections.put("Name", 1);
  DBCursor cursor = coll.find(criteria, projections);
  while(cursor.hasNext()) {
    BasicDBObject obj = (BasicDBObject) cursor.next();
    jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    BasicDBList name = (BasicDBList) obj.get("Name");
    jsonobj.put("Incident Date", obj.getString("Incident Date"));
    jsonobj.put("Longitude", obj.getString("Longitude"));
    jsonobj.put("Latitude", obj.getString("Latitude"));
    jsonobj.put("Address", obj.getString("Address"));
    jsonobj.put("Status", obj.getString("Status"));
    jsonobj.put("Name", name);
    jsonarray.put(jsonobj);
  }
  return jsonarray;
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to parse the json using org.json library, following is the code    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonarray);      System.out.println(json.getString("Status"));

Comment: But I am getting this error JSONObject["Status"] not found. Can you please help.

Comment: @Parag look like some typo mistake replace `System.out.println(json.getString("Status")); ` to `System.out.println(obj.getString("Status")); `

Comment: Sorry about that.I changed it, but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: @Parag I don't understand why you put again `jsonarray` into `jsonobject` and find `key`. For more [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254039/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-mongodb-by-its-key-name) and I personally recommends [java mongo tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-mongodb-tutorials/) this guy explain very well mongo with java may this help you .

Comment: Thank you for the link, but I have already completed that tutorial. I want to send the json from servlet to jsp(maybe on different server), because after some time the volume of data will be huge.

Comment: @Parag you can not directly do this `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonarray)` and access `obj.getString("Status"))` you may do some thing like this `jsonarray.getJSONObject(0).getString("Status"));` or `for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonarray.length() ; i++){
    System.out.println(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("Status"));
}`

Comment: That worked...thank you so much sir. You have been very helpful. Thanks Again. :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Rename your second key "Incident Date" to "Incident_Date". Usually json key names are with lower cases but nevermind.
After that if you want to use Gson to have your json object parsed into an object the smooth but harder way is to create a java object similar to your json object. Something like that:

```
public class MyJSONObject {

    private String Address;
    private String Incident_Date;
    private String Latitude;
    private String Longitude;
    private List Name;
    private String Status;
    private _id _id;

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public String getIncident_Date() {
        return this.Incident_Date;
    }

    public void setIncident_Date(String incident_date) {
        this.Incident_Date = incident_date;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return this.Latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.Latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return this.Longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.Longitude = longitude;
    }

    public List getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(List name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return this.Status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.Status = status;
    }

    public _id get_id() {
        return this._id;
    }

    public void set_id(_id _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }
}
```

And your _id part of the json:

```
public class _id {

    private String $oid;

    public String get$oid() {
        return this.$oid;
    }

    public void set$oid(String $oid) {
        this.$oid = $oid;
    }
}
```

If you have your json into a string for example you can use Gson to parse it and get an instance ot MyJSONObject like that:

```
String jsonString = "{ \"_id\" : { \"$oid\" : \"5540cae37a104f6bbfe7c9f5\"} , \"Incident_Date\" : \"30/4/2015\" , \"Longitude\" : \"77.61528809\" , \"Latitude\" : \"12.9245331\" , \"Address\" : \"Mumbai\" , \"Status\" : \"Ok\" , \"Name\" : [ \"1.ABC\" , \"2.XYZ\" , \"3.PQR\"]}";

        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
        MyJSONObject myJSONObject = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyJSONObject.class);
```

Done - `myJSONObject` is now filled with your json object.

Comment: But the format of MongoDb cursor object is different that jsonString.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is, you are trying to parse your JsonArray to Jsonobject (The line at which you are getting the error).
If you serialize the cursor and parse it then it will return you jsonArray not jsonObject directly. Instead of that you can simply iterate over the cursor and add it in jsonArray (Please refer to below code snippet )

`

```
FindIterable<Document> findIterable = collection.find(struct.searchQueryObject);
MongoCursor<Document> cur = findIterable.cursor();  
JsonArray responses = new JsonArray();
while(cur.hasNext()) {
    Document doc = cur.next();
    responses.add(doc.toJson());
}
```

`

or you can simply change getAsJsonObject() with getAsJsonArray() (but make sure the JsonElement is not null.) (Please refer below code snippet ).

```
JSON json =new JSON();
String serialize = json.serialize(cursor);//make sure string is not empty or null
JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(serialize);
System.out.println(jelement);
JsonArray  jArray = jelement.getAsJsonArray();
System.out.println(jArray);
```

I hope this helps.