# Accessing Mongoose Object fields and values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs, mongoose-schema

I have a piece of my ticket schema structured as so -

```
ticketAssignment : [{
        isAssigned : {type: Boolean, default:false},
        assignee : {type: String, default: null}
    }]
```

when I console.log ticket.ticketAssignment[0] I receive the following -

```
{ isAssigned: true, assignee: '5ddc6e151c816d4154ab32d7' }
```

My question is how would I go about accessing just the individual fields i.e.

```
isAssigned: true
```

AND

```
assignee: '5ddc6e151c816d4154ab32d7'
```

EDIT:

using `ticket.ticketAssignment[0].assignee` yields an error `Cannot read property 'assignee' of undefined` which is strange since the property of ticket.ticketAssignment[0] is defined before I try and access the assignee/isAssigned fields of the object.

using `tickets[i].ticketAssignment[0]['assignee']` generates the exact same error.

Comment: you've to access either by doing 'ticket.ticketAssignment[0].isAssigned' or by 'ticket.ticketAssignment[0].assignee' on the response object, mongoose schemas are for writes, on reads you might see entire document being returned, then you've to retrieve particular keys using `.` notation or  'ticket.ticketAssignment[0]['isAssigned']' or tune your queries using projection in mongoDB to return only needed fields..

Comment: To build up on @srinivasy's advice, I'd say go and give [this page a read](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve a value from mongoDB, by its key name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254039/how-to-retrieve-a-value-from-mongodb-by-its-key-name)